# Using Express Router in routes.js

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I am currently using routes in **app.js** as below:

```
// Router configuration
var router = express.Router();

router.route('/user')
    .get(userController.getUser)
    .post(userController.postUser);

app.use('/api', router);
```

Is it possible to put Express router routes in another file like **routes.js** and call from app.js? I tried with `app.get` in routes.js and it is working. But it is annoying to add `/api` for prefix in all routes as below.

```
module.exports = function(app){
    app.get('/user', userController.getUser);
};
```

Or, is there anyway to use namespace in `app.get` too? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just do what you're doing, but in your route file?

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.route('/user')
    .get(userController.getUser)
    .post(userController.postUser);

module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use('/api', router);
};
```

Then you'd have in your app.js file

```
require('./routes.js')(app);
```

Routers support namespaces too, so you could even do

```
app.use('/', require('./routes.js'));
```

And in your routes file (this can be split across files for modularity)

```
var express = require('express');
var mainRouter = express.Router();
var userRouter = express.Router();

userRouter.route('/user')
    .get(userController.getUser)
    .post(userController.postUser);

mainRouter.use('/api', userRouter);

module.exports = mainRouter;
```

Comment: Thank you Ben. Your answer gets me clear about express router.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to declare your routes in *app.js*, in fact, it's better to have each route in its own file, so you can write a *routes/my_route.js* file as:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Then in *app.js*:

```
var express = require("express");
var myRoute = require("./routes/my_route");
var app = express();
app.use("/my-route", myRoute);
```